# Room @Query doesn't work with a pre-created SQLite VIEW

Tags: kotlin, android-room

It appears that @Query Room annotation would not recognize a pre-existing VIEW in a pre-created SQLite schema .

Is there any work-around ?

(I'm aware that the Room API can generate VIEWs on SQLite, but in my use-case I want an ad-hoc @Query to work with a hand-created pre-existing VIEW on SQLite )

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use an `@RawQuery` (in short Room knows nothing about the view and hence). See https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RawQuery